# Morring Matrix with Google Drive SpreadSheets

Tags: matrix, google-sheets, drive, inverse

I'm trying to mirror a matrix over a diagonal, but i don't know how. 
Is there a way of getting the cell in some position of a selection of the type C5:P5 ?

[image]

I'm looking for a function for each column or row of the inferior part of the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula in the first cell B4:

```
=OFFSET(B4,-1*(ROW(1:1)-COLUMN(A:A)+1),ROW(1:1)-COLUMN(A:A)+1,1,1)
```

Change the B4 to the cell address into which cell you placed the formula.

Then copy and paste the cell into all the desired cells.

[image]

It works in Google as well:

[image]

Comment: Mmm, is not working for me. Why are u using row 1:1 and column A:A?

Comment: Those are counters, they resolve to 1,2,3,...  Do not change those yourself.  As teh cell is copied/dragged it will change on its own.  The only thing you need to change is the `B3` reference to the first cell.

Comment: As per your edit you would only change `B3` to `B4` And put it in B4.  Then copy the cell and paste it into the others.

Comment: @Xhark I changed mine to match more like yours.

Comment: I'm using google spreadsheets. Should that make any difference?

Comment: @Xhark please stop editing your question, it makes my answer irrelevant.   Please roll it back to the last one.  The reason you are not having luck is you need to change the `,` to `;`.  Your local settings require `;` to delineate between the criteria, mine requires `,`.

Comment: That was it. Thanks so much and sorry.